# slice tensor of tensors using boolean tensor

Tags: pytorch

Having two tensors :inputs_tokens is a batch of 20x300 of token ids
and seq_A is my model output with size of [20, 300, 512] (512 vector for each of the tokens in the batch)

```
seq_A.size()
Out[1]: torch.Size([20, 300, 512])

inputs_tokens.size()
torch.Size([20, 300])
```

I would like to get only the vectors of the token 101 (CLS) as follow:

```
cls_tokens = (inputs_tokens == 101) 
cls_tokens
Out[4]: 
tensor([[ True, False, False,  ..., False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  ..., False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  ..., False, False, False], ...
```

How do I slice seq_A to get only the vectors which are true in cls_tokens for each batch?
when I do

```
seq_A[cls_tokens].size()
Out[7]: torch.Size([278, 512])
```

but I still need it to bee in the size of [20 x N x 512 ] (otherwise I don't know to which sample it belongs)

Comment: Are there `N` *101* tokens on each batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;** You can't, all sequences must have the same size along a given axis.

---

Take this simplified example:

```
>>> inputs_tokens = torch.tensor([[  1, 101,  18, 101,   9],
                                  [  1,   2, 101, 101, 101]])
>>> inputs_tokens.shape
torch.Size([2, 5])

>>> cls_tokens = inputs_tokens == 101
tensor([[False,  True, False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Indexing `inputs_tokens` with the `cls_tokens` mask comes down to *reducing* `inputs_tokens` to `cls_tokens`'s `true` values. In a general case where there is a different number of `true` values per batch, keeping the shape is impossible.

Following the above example, here is `seq_A`:

```
>>> seq_A = torch.rand(2, 5, 1)
tensor([[[0.4644],
         [0.7656],
         [0.3951],
         [0.6384],
         [0.1090]],

        [[0.6754],
         [0.0144],
         [0.7154],
         [0.5805],
         [0.5274]]])
```

According to your example, you would expect to have an output shape of  `(2, N, 1)`. What would `N` be? `3`? What about the first batch which only as *2* `true` values? The resulting tensor can't have different sizes (*2* and *3* on `axis=1`). Hence: "all sequences on `axis=1` must have the same size".

---

If however, you are expecting each batch to have the same number of tokens *101*, then you could get away with a broadcast of your indexed tensor:

```
>>> inputs_tokens = torch.tensor([[  1, 101, 101, 101,   9],
                                  [  1,   2, 101, 101, 101]])
>>> inputs_tokens.shape

>>> N = cls_tokens[0].sum()
3
```

Here remember, I'm assuming you have:

```
>>> assert all(cls_tokens.sum(axis=1) == N)
```

Therefore the desired output (with shape `(2, 3, 1)`) is:

```
>>> seq_A[cls_tokens].reshape(seq_A.size(0), N, -1)
tensor([[[0.7656],
         [0.3951],
         [0.6384]],

        [[0.7154],
         [0.5805],
         [0.5274]]])
```

---

*Edit* - if you really want to do this though you would require the use of a list comprehension:

```
>>> [seq_A[i, cls_tokens[i]] for i in range(cls_tokens.size(0))]
[ tensor([[0.7656],
          [0.6384]]), 
  tensor([[0.7154],
          [0.5805],
          [0.5274]]) ]
```

Comment: Great answer @ivan. Is there another way to extract all those vectors? since as you suggested the amount of them is different between each batch.